# Are scratched glass bowls safe to use?

Tags: food-safety, equipment

I'll be changing my dinnerware soon and I'm looking for something durable and non-toxic. Are glass bowls/plates more susceptible to spoon and fork scratches? Are scratched glass bowls/plates safe to use? Am I supposed to eat with wooden cutlery? The reason I ask this is that, I've got heatresistant cookware for oven and microwave and its user's guide says "don't use fractured,cracked or scratched products".

Answer (score 5):

The reason not to use scratched glass bakeware is because the internal stresses encountered during heating can (rarely) cause the bakeware to violently fracture along the scratches. That doesn't really apply to glass tableware, which doesn't encounter the same temperatures (though cracked tableware, of multiple materials, will occasionally break from thermal stress in the dishwasher).

Incidentally, glass bakeware and tableware should be made from borosilicate glass, which cannot be scratched by steel cutlery.

EDIT: Also: Don't use glass tableware for hot food. Irrespective of safety issues, the thermal density and thermal conductivity of glass means that it will quickly wick away heat from any food which is placed on it. Glass plates are fine for salads and stuff, but they don't make good general-use dinner plates.

Comment: 100% agree with the borosilicate part. To add to this, I would say that some Pyrex bakeware is totally safe while some is unsafe to cook at relatively high temperatures, due to basically several brands being called the same name and not producing the same stuff, [Here is a cool guide](https://external-preview.redd.it/SzFJkj8BqqeWBlcWIMz0ewXY3hB0SzHC-Dk8m_AmU-g.jpg?auto=webp&s=acaf51acb0cb69100f01e8936cbdc4d3022c3a6c) about it.

Comment: You can use glass plates for hot food fine, you just need to have a "charger" (and insulating under-plate disk or basket) underneath it.  Our Passover set was glass, and we used it for many holidays.

Comment: Even Correlle (vitrelle) develops micro-fractures over time that will cause it to explode if dropped. How it's made: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW8egUCzw-k

Comment: Also, the almost-invisible food particles that get stuck in the indents of the scratch are impossible to remove, hence making those plates a good home for bacteria